# Open CSV data with encoding

Tags: excel, vba, csv, encoding

Using Excel 2016, I have a csv file named "Abc-123.csv" I already opened in Excel, so right now I have one sheet with the csv.
I want to open the **same file again (ActiveWorkbook)** using **Data > From Text/CSV** and use **encoding 1252: Western European (Windows)**

I recorded a macro, and then changed it to a function so it can receive an outer csv file.

What I need is help making this macro more general for **cases where my csv will have a different name**

```
Function Data_CSV(CSVFile)
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Abc-123", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\CSV\Abc-123.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=43, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Sales Record Number"", Int64.Type}, {""User" & _
        " Id"", type text}, {""Buyer Fullname"", type text}, {""Buyer Phone Number"", type text}, {""Buyer Email"", type text}, {""Buyer Address 1"", type text}, {""Buyer Address 2"", type text}, {""Buyer City"", type text}, {""Buyer State"", type text}, {""Buyer Zip"", type text}, {""Buyer Country"", type text}, {""Order ID"", type number}, {""Item ID"", type number}, {""Tr" & _
        "ansaction ID"", type number}, {""Item Title"", type text}, {""Quantity"", Int64.Type}, {""Sale Price"", type text}, {""Shipping And Handling"", type text}, {""Sales Tax"", type text}, {""Insurance"", type text}, {""eBay Collected Tax"", type text}, {""Total Price"", type text}, {""Payment Method"", type text}, {""PayPal Transaction ID"", type text}, {""Sale Date"", " & _
        "type date}, {""Checkout Date"", type date}, {""Paid on Date"", type date}, {""Shipped on Date"", type date}, {""Shipping Service"", type text}, {""Feedback Left"", type text}, {""Feedback Received"", type text}, {""Notes to Yourself"", type text}, {""Custom Label"", type text}, {""Listed On"", type text}, {""Sold On"", type text}, {""Private Notes"", type text}, {""" & _
        "Product ID Type"", type text}, {""Product ID Value"", type text}, {""Product ID Value 2"", type text}, {""Variation Details"", type text}, {""Product Reference ID"", type text}, {""Tracking Number"", type text}, {""Phone"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Abc-123;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Abc-123]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Abc_123"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

[Macro Setup Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo6fu.png)

I really prefer subroutines over functions for importing data, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt to a function if that's what you need.

First make 3 named ranges: 'FileName', 'SheetName' and 'Extension'.
Then paste this code over the code that you're using.
I'd recommend adding a button to your spreadsheet if you're doing this frequently.

This works with many text file types (.csv, .txt, etc.):

```
Sub LoadData()
    'This subroutine will load data from text-formatted files without opening them.
    Dim ThisWB As Workbook

    Set ThisWB = ThisWorkbook
    filename = Range("FileName").Value
    SheetName = Range("SheetName").Value
    extension = Range("Extension").Value

    If extension = ".csv" Then
        isCSV = True
    Else
        isCSV = False
    End If


    If (SheetExists(SheetName, ThisWB) = False) Then
        Call createSheet(SheetName, ThisWB)
    End If

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filename, Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = (Not (isCSV))
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = isCSV
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Item(ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count).Delete

End Sub

Function SheetExists(ByVal shtName As String, Optional WB As Workbook) As Boolean
    'This subroutine will test to see if a worksheet already exists within a workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = WB.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function

Sub createSheet(ByVal shtName As String, WB As Workbook)
    'This subroutine will create a sheet for the data to be imported to, if that sheet does not already exist.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With WB
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = shtName
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Wow this is very ellaborate and helpful, but i think it misses the part where it should open the files with 1252 encoding, my main goal is to read the accented characters. any suggestions?

Comment: I remind that I want to open ActiveWorkbook again but encoded (this makes getting filename and path and extension easier)

Comment: Hi Assaf, sorry that it took me a while to get back to this. Turns out that all we needed to do was change the '850' in the macro above to be 1252 - and wallah! It should work now. Let me know if there is anything else I can help with. Cheers!